Difference between にする vs ~づける noun suffix
There is a somewhat limited set of nouns that can go with the verbal suffix ~づける, which according to 大辞林 has the following definitions:

①その物事を他につけ加える意を表す。
「元気━・ける」 「関係━・ける」
②その物事・事柄を他に与える意を表す。
「位置━・ける」
「性格━・ける」

Taking a common example like 義務付ける "to make obligatory/compulsory" and an example sentence:

シートベルトの着用を義務づける

...I wonder the difference between 義務づける here and 義務にする.
It seems like both of these phrases could mean "To make the wearing of seatbelts obligatory".
I've also been able to find a good amount of uses of 義務にする when searching, so it makes me wonder the nuance between these two structures.

In formal or academic contexts, 義務づける is usually preferred, while 義務にする would sound a little immature or unpolished. In particular, 義務にする is unlikely to appear in legal texts. On the other hand, 義務づける might be too difficult for elementary school students around age 10, so 義務にする might be more suitable for textbooks aimed at them. In everyday conversations between adults, either expression should be fine.
However, note that you shouldn't try to generalize this pattern. 元気づける means "to encourage" or "to lift someone's mood/spirit", while 元気にする is more like "to heal" or "to get someone well". 位置づける is a common verb, but 位置にする is simply nonsense. You basically need to memorize how to use each -づける verb individually.
